# Does Adventure Sync also track distance?

Tags: pokemon-go

Adventure Sync can now be activated to track your steps (like a pedometer) while your phone is locked.  Will Pokemon GO still track distance (with GPS) when the phone is unlocked and Pokemon GO running?

I do a bit of bike riding and do not want to lose out on the current (GPS) distance system.  If both tracking systems work, Adventure Sync would be nice to be able to also count my steps around the office and house.

Comment: Please clarify or edit your question to specify which app you are referring to.

Comment: @Jerry Adventure Sync isn't a third party app. It is a new feature within Pokemon Go. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes, I am referring to the new feature in Pokemon-Go.

Comment: Well, the description of Adventure Sync explicitly says the Pokemon GO app is not open and works with Apple Health and Google Fit, but the question asks about "when the phone is unlocked with the app up?"  Also, in the second paragraph, what is meant by both?

Comment: @Jerry The question is intended to be independent of the 3rd party apps, asking if Pokemon Go will still track distance when the app is open.
In the second paragraph, both refers to both the old style of distance tracking in Pokemon Go and the new style which does not require the app to be open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Adventure Sync also tracks distance.

I tested by locking the phone and riding my bike.  The distance ridden did not show up immediately, but it did show up in the app.

If you are using Android, be sure to have Google Fit installed and configured.
Note: If you open the app, distance is tracked as normal (without the refresh lag).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will still track your progress.

Admittedly, I know this out of ignorance of how the app actually worked to begin with. I was unsure as to how the app tracked the progress of my Pokémon Go progress, so I continued to leave the app open as I walked, and I eventually received an alert - "You have walked 5km", and received 20 Pokeballs upon collection.

The idea of the app is that you don't *need* to keep the app open, but in doing so, you won't be able to visit Pokestops, or gyms, or catch Pokémon with the app closed - it is used purely to help collect candies for your Buddy, and hatch eggs.

Comment: Hi Ben, this does not answer the question, since when the app was open you were still walking, so it might have been tracking your steps instead of the distance you traveled.  To run a test, you would need to ride a bike with the app open and see if it is still tracking distance or if it only tracks steps.

Comment: Pokemon Go does not track "steps". It uses Google Maps to track your movement and speed, when the app is open. You can now choose sync it with Adventure Sync, which does the same thing when it is closed. There is no "step" tracking in either of these apps.

Comment: "Adventure Sync seems to work by tapping into your phone's on-board fitness-tracking software, either Apple's Health or Google Fit, then using the step data your phone tracks and translating it into the game." [https://www.gamespot.com/articles/pokemon-go-finally-stops-destroying-your-battery-w/1100-6463026/](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/pokemon-go-finally-stops-destroying-your-battery-w/1100-6463026/)

Comment: "There may be a delay of up to several hours to sync your steps, so you may not always see the most up to date data."[https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002025707-Adventure-Sync](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002025707-Adventure-Sync)

Comment: There is also a new set of metrics on the trainer screen which includes steps and calories (though mine have locks over them since I have not yet turned on Adventure Sync (since I am not sure if it changes how distance is calculated).  I will do some research on the fitness tracker side to see if they commonly track distance.

Comment: It appears you have to have Google Fit installed for this feature to work (though none of the activation tutorials mentioned that).  Looking at the Google Fit [reviews](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true), it is hard to tell but it seems like it should automatically track your workouts and distance by GPS.  Of course the reviews seem to indicate that the app does not do a good job tracking since an update at the end of October, coincidence?

Comment: @Trisped Google Fit does track steps (I have used it for several years), as well as GPS. It will equally track both walking on a treadmill (steps) and activities like cycling or kayaking (GPS). Adventure Sync is just picking up data from Google Fit, so it should work with both.

Comment: When you enable Adventure Sync it states "Let Pokemon GO count your **steps** while the game is closed to help incubate your eggs and find more candy!"